# Manage a codebase or offline PHP.net information

Tags: php

This is a 2 part question.

1) Is there some sort of program that will download all the [php.net](http://www.php.net) documentation **with** user contributed comments in tact for ofline viewing?

2) I really love using stackoverflow and adding questions that are useful to me as a favorite.  This gave me the idea, it would be extremely useful if I had a software of some sort that would basicly let me have an offline version of stackoverflow, not all the topics here but more like an app where I can add topics and store information including code snippets and such in an easy to navigate system like stackoverflow.  Hope I am explaining myself properly.

I would like to have a page with topics, I click on 1 and it would load a page similar in format to a stackoverflow page and I could have my own comments and code on it including a search function.

I am considering building such an app in php/mysql but if something exists already I would like to see it as I am sure this could be useful to many programmers to keep track of code snippets and info/notes.

So does anyone know if something like this exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part, take a look at [How to host the php.net manual on your laptop for offline use](http://www.jaisenmathai.com/blog/2009/03/03/how-to-host-the-phpnet-manual-on-your-laptop-for-offline-use/).

For StackOverflow, [data dumps are produced monthly](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/stack-overflow-creative-commons-data-dump/). You can use one of those offline.

Comment: that data dump is very nice, not exactly what I meant but still very useful, thanks!